# setting variable with unknown name in bash

Tags: bash, variables

I would like to set a variable which name is stored in a file (is an output of a sed executed earlier)

the file would look like:
`py1`
so setting our variable would be like: set `cat file`=value
but echoing `$py1` gives me nothing.

Is that possible with bash version 2.05?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `eval`:

```
eval "$(cat file)=value"
```

Update: The command substitution `$(cat file)` can be replaced by the equivalent but faster `$(< file)`.

Comment: Yeah, that was simple... haven't heared before 'bout that eval (evil :)) function!Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This is the "preferred" way to do it (bash) without using `cat` or `eval`

```
declare $(<file)=value
```

Comment: well bash gives me this: `declare: Command not found.` so i guess i have to use eval

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use eval

```
eval $(cat file)=value
```